# Dismiss reactstrap modal when clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I want the modal to close when clicking outside of it just like in the examples: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/ but it doesn't happen:

https://codesandbox.io/s/x9rx5jx34q

Press the button and then click anywhere else and nothing happens. The same happens in my code.

I tried to add `backdrop={true}` as a prop for the modal but it didn't work.

So what does reactstrap uses in their examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `bootstrap` in your dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "reactstrap": "6.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.1"
  },
```

As stated in the documentation: https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap#adding-bootstrap

I modified your example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/m73w9j289

Comment: I have it in the root in my app and these imports in my packacge.json, do you know what exactly was missing?

Comment: @shinzou I just added the dependency in package.json and added the CSS import in the index.js `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';`

Comment: I meant what exactly changed this behavior from the css file?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just noticed that in the example you provided, it didn't look like a popup, it looked like a simple div without any CSS.

Comment: @shinzou Please accept if it answers your question.

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question. I'll get back to this later and try to reproduce online.

Comment: My problem was that I didn't send the toggle function to the modal.

Answer (score 14):

Quoting what shinzou said as it happened to me as well:

If you set `backdrop={true}` **you must also set `toggle={fnToggle}`** otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks dear, but this solution did not work for me.

Comment: Hi @woseth, then what is the use of `keyboard` prop?

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Modal, ModalBody } from "reactstrap";

const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

<Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={() => setModal(false)} >
<ModalBody>
....
<ModalBody>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `backdrop="static"` and `keyboard={false}` as shown it will solve the problem

```js
<Modal isOpen={isVisible} size='sm' toggle={() => setVisible(!isVisible)}  backdrop="static" keyboard={false}>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **backdrop={'static'}** in Modal, So that we control the outside click. Modal won't close on clicking outside of Modal.

Eg: <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen} toggle={this.props.toggleModal} **backdrop={'static'}**>

Comment: This is incorrect. Straight from method signature, ts, documentation: Include a backdrop component. A `static`backdrop will not trigger a Modal onHide when clicked.
     
    `backdrop?: true | false | 'static';`